# how to assign the output of the command in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

how can I assign the output of the below command to a variable in a while loop?

```
echo $(( `date +%s` - `stat -L --format %Y $"/root/path/$output_file"` ))
```

This command checks the age of the file in a path, echo works successfully, but when I want to assign it to a variable, it give "command not found" error or may be I do not know how to assign the value of it to a variable properly.

Comment: `$"..."` is syntax for looking up strings in translation tables. Surely your filenames aren't mapped through a `.po` file to their native-language equivalents.

Comment: Anyhow, it would be very helpful here if you showed the syntax whereby you attempted to do the assignment. Right now you're showing us your *working* code, whereas we'd need to see your *broken* code (and the specific error it generates) to know what's wrong. (Spaces around the `=` are one of the most common mistakes that will cause a "command not found" from an assignment, btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
age=$(( `date +%s` - `stat -L --format %Y $"/root/path/$output_file"` ))
```

Best to use `$(...)` rather than backticks. And the `$` isn't needed before the file name.

```
age=$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -L --format %Y "/root/path/$output_file") ))
```